# How to move the position of a block by 100px with each click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help solving the following problem. The task is to change the position of the block by 100 pixels with each click.

For example, the first position of the block is 0 pixels. If you clicked once, the position of the block along the X axis changes by 100 pixels. If you clicked a second time, the position of the block changed by another 100 pixels (200 pixels total) (from the left edge), and so on.

But the position of the block should be limited to 800 pixels, that is, it is possible to click only 8 times.

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```

Comment: It will help to answer your question to have more details included. do you have anything more than just a div element in your document?are you able to position it now, manually and need help with the javascript? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example some very very helpful reading material: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ this is the 'www manual'

Comment: I think you wont get any help unless you show what you tried and explain what is stocking you.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+move+box+right+by+pixels+with+each+click) of [JavaScript move object by button by X px](/q/59510107/4642212). The rest can be done with a simple [`if` statement](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). Where in the process of writing your code are you stuck? Since this is your task, you are strongly encouraged to try implementing this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the current position in javascript and then set the onClick function to update the position variable (`pos+=100; pos=Math.min(pos,800)`) and set the new position of the box.